What is $F$ and what is $P$ in the sentence "$F × dP$ is a total differential"?
The physicist Emilio Segrè, as a student, attended lessons of Calculus given by Francesco Severi and of Analytical Mechanics given by Tullio Levi-Civita. Segrè wrote in his autobiography1

For many months we heard [professor Levi-Civita talking about] the simplifications that occur in mechanics if $F × dP$ is a total differential without the professor ever explaining what a total differential was, and without us ever asking. Levi-Civita trusted our analytical competence, but unfortunately Severi had not mentioned total differentials.

I think that $F$ is a force (a vector) and $P$ a displacement (another vector) and $\times$ is the dot product and so $F\times dP$ is related to the work formula but I am not sure about it; what do you think?
1 Segrè, Emilio. A Mind Always in Motion: The Autobiography of Emilio Segre. Berkeley:  University of California Press,  c1993 1993. See Chapter 3 at https://publishing.cdlib.org/ucpressebooks/view?docId=ft700007rb&chunk.id=d0e600&toc.depth=1&toc.id=&brand=ucpress

P normally refers to momentum.  But I don't know what force times momentum would mean.

It seems that here the cross product $\times$ is used in place of the dot product $\cdot$.
Under this modern re-formulation, the text seems to be more understandable.
Saying that $${\bf F}\cdot d{\bf x}=\sum_{k=1}^3 F_k dx_k$$ is a "total differential" -- in the modern language it is an "exact form" --  it is the same as declaring that the force ${\bf F}= (F_1,F_2,F_3)$ is conservative. In other words
$${\bf F}({\bf x})= - \nabla_{\bf x} U({\bf x})$$
for some potential energy $U=U(\bf x)$.

My understanding of your question:
$$dW = \textbf{F}\times d\textbf{p}$$
is the work,or in clearer notation:
$$dW = \textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{r}$$
And things will be simpler if this expression is a total derivative.
The total derivative is just the linear approximation of a tiny increment in the function.In one dimension,the total derivative of a function $V(x)$ is just:
$$dV = V'dx$$
In three dimension it's similar,just replace the derivative with gradiant:
$$dV = \nabla V \cdot d\textbf{r} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial V}{\partial z}dz$$
So now it's clear that if you want the expression of work to be a total derivative,the force has to be a gradiant of a scalar function,in reality some potential energy.
$$F = -\nabla V$$
(The negative sign is just for convenience)
And yes, it indeed will be much simpler if the force is derivable from a potential energy.Often the total energy will be conserved,the lagragian and hamiltonian formalisms can be applied easily.If the force is not derivable from potential energy,friction for example, then the work cannot be written as a definite change in a scalar function.
